# How to simplify a trigonometric expression using python?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, sympy

I have an expression like this calculated by Sympy:

```
-1.0*pi*(-1.0*sin(1.0*t) - 0.025*cos(1.0*t) + 4.0*cos(2.0*t))
```

Then I try a lot of options provided for the simplification of expression but they don't work too much.

When I use `expand_trig()`, it returns:

```
pi*(1.0*sin(1.0*t) + 0.025*cos(1.0*t) - 4.0*cos(2.0*t))
```

But when I use Mathematica, it returns:

```
-25.0542 Cos t + 3.14159 Sin t
```

How can I reach a result like Mathematica using Python? And if I want to  simplify even more the expression given by Mathematica, what should I do?

Comment: What makes you think that your expression can be simplified? Have you tried plotting the three functions in your question? While the first two are the same, the one from Mathematica is an entirely different function.

Comment: Okay, you are right. It is really strange that Mathematica gave me this. But BTW, can you tell me how to simplify this simple expression using python: sympy.simplify(math.pi*(1.0*sympy.sin(1.0*t) + 0.025*sympy.cos(1.0*t))). For me, we can combine them into one expression. But I cannot find the way. These two expressions are always separated. THX!

Comment: You're right - but I don't know how to do it in python.

Comment: Fyi, Mma gives the same answer as Sympy.

Comment: voting to close as the "expected" output shown is simply wrong. @hyoukai if you wish to fix/clarify the question then edit the question, don't pose revisions in comments.

Comment: I see.If you literally type that python syntax expression into mathematica, the `sin` and `cos`, being lower case, are simply undefined symbols and since you don't have mathematica function argument  notation `Cos[2.0 t]` it just multiplies everything out.  `(0.025 - 2*4)*pi ->-25.0542`.   You must actually have used upcase `Pi` though.

Answer (score 5):

SymPy can expand the `cos(2*t)` term, but it doesn't recognize it with the floating point coefficient.  `expand_trig(cos(2*t))` works (it gives `2*cos(t)**2 - 1`). I also recommend using `cos(t)` instead of `cos(1.0*t)`, as SymPy will see them as different (e.g., `cos(t) - cos(1.0*t)` doesn't simplify to 0). I also recommend using `sympy.pi`, as it is symbolic and can symbolically simplify (e.g., `sin(sympy.pi)` gives `0`; `sin(math.pi)` does not).

As others have noted, the expression you claim was returned by Mathematica is not equivalent, as a simple plot will show.